# How do i add Azure health check to an existing .net app in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I have a .net app that is deployed to Azure. I need to add azure health check .
Do i need to make some modifications to the app and redeploy ?
What are the steps that i need to take to add Health Check to the app ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make sure there is an endpoint available that can be checked. This can be an existing endpoint or a dedicated endpoint just for this purpose. Other than that you have to modify the settings as described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet#enable-health-check):

[image]

Personally I think your health check endpoint should only indicate whether the web app (on that instance) is running. It should *not* be used to check external dependencies like database. A failed connection to a database won't likely be restored by killing the instance and spinning up a new one.

For dependency checks I suggest using an [Application Insights availability test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-overview) to the endpoint that checks dependencies. Then, set an alert on failed results and act accordingly.

Comment: so you mean in the .net app i must have an endpoint api/health ? And in that endpoint i can try to connect to a database and if successful return a success ?